# add and remove div after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ramswarnak/kjTBG/14/)**

In this demo when I click `pop1` it removes the div. When I then click on `pop2` it remove it and adds pop1.

But when I click `pop1`, it (pop1) should remove and add `pop0`, then I click `pop2` where it should remove and add `pop1`, when I click `pop3`, `pop3` should remove and add `pop2`.

**JS:**

```
$(".pop").bind('click', function(){
    $('.pop').show();
   $(this).hide();     
})
```

In my page, there must always be 3 boxes.

Comment: There is no pop0. Do you want to create pop0 dynamically?

Comment: check the demo. in css there's pop0. i need to replace pop1 to pop0.

Comment: Can't really tell what you want but this has 3 boxes always http://jsfiddle.net/kjTBG/18/

Comment: Well you are not really removing or adding anything, just hiding it or showing it. Also why would you hide then show something? Doesn't make sense

Comment: Could you explain whether any of the answers are at least partially related to what you are trying to do? It's easier to find the right solution if we know what's wrong/right with the existing ones.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not at all sure what you are trying to do. There wasn't even an element with the ID "pop0" in your example, but I added it and hid it by default with `$("#pop0").hide();`:

http://jsfiddle.net/kjTBG/16/

HTML:

```
<a href='#'><div id="pop0" class="pop"></div></a>
<a href='#'><div id="pop1" class="pop"></div></a>
<a href='#'><div id="pop2" class="pop"></div></a>
<a href='#'><div id="pop3" class="pop"></div></a>
```

JS:

```
$("#pop0").hide(); // Initially hide #pop0 so it isn't visible.
$(".pop").bind('click', function(){
    $('.pop').show();
   $(this).hide();     
})
```

Please elaborate on what you are trying to do. Rephrase your question and use whole sentences please. Try to describe it more abstractly if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("body").on('click', '.pop', function(){
    if($('.pop').length == 3) {
        $('.pop').eq(0).before('<a href="#"><div id="pop0" class="pop"></div></a>');
    }
    $('.pop').show();
   $(this).hide();     
});
```

Is this what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/kjTBG/17/

**Edit:**

```
$("body").on('click', '.pop', function(){
    if($('.pop').length == 3) {
        $('.pop').last().after('<a href="#"><div id="pop0" class="pop"></div></a>');
    }
    $('.pop').show();
   $(this).hide();     
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kjTBG/24/

Comment: yes this is what i looked.But if you please excuse, i need to change the idea. i need to appear all 4 divs but when i click pop0, it should disappear and  appear from end of the divs (i mean after pop3).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just trying to swap the IDs to change the colors.

In that case try this:

```
var id = "pop0";
$(".pop").bind('click', function(){
    var oldId = $(this).attr('id');
    $(this).attr('id', id);
    id = oldId;
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kjTBG/20/

Basically what it does is this:

Initially, the three DIVs have the IDs "pop1", "pop2" and "pop3".

Example 1: When you click on "pop1" first, its ID changes to "pop0".
When you then click on "pop2", its ID changes to "pop1".
And so on.

Example 2: When you click on "pop2" first, its ID changes to "pop0".
When you then click on "pop1", its ID changes to "pop2".
And so on.

It keeps track of the original ID of the last "pop" you clicked on and then swaps that out with the ID of the next "pop" you click on.

Comment: i need to change the idea. i need to appear all 4 divs but when i click pop0, it should disappear and  appear from end of the divs (i mean after pop3).

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kjTBG/23/)**

```
$(".pop").bind('click', function(){
    $('.pop').show();
    $(this).hide().prev().show();
})
```

Answer (score -1):

This is what you are looking for: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/kjTBG/19/)

```
<a href='#'><div id="pop0" class="pop"></div></a>
<a href='#'><div id="pop1" class="pop"></div></a>
<a href='#'><div id="pop2" class="pop"></div></a>
<a href='#'><div id="pop3" class="pop"></div></a>

$(".pop").bind('click', function(){
    $('.pop').show();
   $(this).hide();     
})
```

Comment: No it's not. He said he wants three visible at all times.