# remove Div and appear it another place

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like 4 `div`s to appear. When I click any of the `div`s, I would like that `div` to move to the end.

So, for example, if the first div is clicked, it should become the last div.

The HTML:

```
<a href='#'><div id="pop0" class="pop"></div></a>
<a href='#'><div id="pop1" class="pop"></div></a>
<a href='#'><div id="pop2" class="pop"></div></a>
<a href='#'><div id="pop3" class="pop"></div></a>
```

The CSS:

```
#pop0 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: yellow;
    position: relative;
}
#pop1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
}
#pop2 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
    position: relative;
}
#pop3 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: green;
    position: relative;
}
```

The jQuery:

```
var id = "pop0";
$(".pop").bind('click', function(){
    var oldId = $(this).attr('id');
    $(this).attr('id', id);
    id = oldId;
})
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ramswarnak/kjTBG/26/)

Comment: man...the English is bad on this.  Really hard to understand what you're saying....can you edit the question to clarify?

Comment: Should your fiddle have a pop0 element?

Comment: if you check the demo, there is 4 ids in css. i need show all divs, but when i click one div, it should remove and add end of the other divs. divs are pop0, pop1, pop2, pop3. when click pop0, those divs must be like this, pop1, pop2, pop3, pop0.

Comment: You just asked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18151488/add-and-remove-div-after-click

Comment: i got 30 minor  reputation for this  question, how ever finally i got the right answer.

Comment: In case you end up wanting a mix of this and your previous question, try this: http://jsfiddle.net/kjTBG/29/

Comment: @user2607456 The reason you're being downvoted is that your questions are really badly phrased. I understand that English may not be your native language, but it's really difficult to figure out what you want exactly. Try to move away from the code and describe the behaviour you want to create in more abstract terms. Use more examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

**JS**

```
$(".pop").on('click', function() {
    // Get the closest anchor container
    var $a =$(this).closest('a');
    // Insert after the last anchor container
    $a.insertAfter('a:last')
})
```

Also `bind` has been superseeded by `on` . Use that to bind event handlers.

Also your html can be cleaned up a bit, by not repeating the same styles. Move the common styles to the same class.

**CSS**

```
.pop{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
}

#pop0 {
    background: yellow;
}
#pop1 {
    background: red;
}
#pop2 {
    background: blue;
}
#pop3 {
    background: green;
}
```

### **[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/kjTBG/28/)**

Comment: thanks Sushanth, i like your answer too. it works.

Comment: Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Using your code which is just bad as you don't have any DOM wrapper element... (except body)

```
$(".pop").bind('click', function(){
    $('body').append($(this).parent());
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tYupC/)

Comment: This doesn't move the div, just copies it.

Comment: @John What copy the DIV??? I'm not cloning here... See, i made you a demo or could you explain what you are talking about?

Comment: Sorry, I see that in the demo, -1 removed.

Comment: thanks roasted, this is what i want.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps just detach the item and append it to the end of the container?

```
$(document).on('click','.pop',null,function(){
    var $pop = $(this);
    var $parent = $pop.parent();
    $pop.detach();
    $parent.append($pop);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rtpt5/3/

Comment: better would be to .detach() element to keep handlers

Comment: thanks brad ii like your answer.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ramswarnak/6tLEg/1/, Can some one edit this Fiddle. but dont change html or css. i  just need javascript.